# Removing successive duplicate occurrences in an array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Is there any way that I can remove the successive duplicates from the array below while only keeping the first one?

The array is shown below:

```
$a=array("1"=>"go","2"=>"stop","3"=>"stop","4"=>"stop","5"=>"stop","6"=>"go","7"=>"go","8"=>"stop");
```

What I want is to have an array that contains:

```
$a=array("1"=>"go","2"=>"stop","3"=>"go","7"=>"stop");
```

Comment: why "3"=>"go" how you get that?

Comment: would it be `..."3"=>"go","4"=>"stop"` instead of `"3"=>"go","7"=>"stop")`?

Comment: yes sean sorry it should have been "4"=>"stop"

Comment: Is it not possible to consider not putting the duplicates in the array to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do something like:

```
if(current($a) !== $new_val)
    $a[] = $new_val;
```

Assuming you're not manipulating that array in between you can use `current()` it's more efficient than counting it each time to check the value at `count($a)-1`

Comment: can you further elaborate on $new_val where would it come from?

Comment: `$new_val` would be the value you're adding eg. "stop" or "go"

Answer (score 9):

Successive duplicates? I don't know about native functions, but this one works. Well almost. Think I understood it wrong. In my function the 7 => "go" is a duplicate of 6 => "go", and 8 => "stop" is the new value...?

```
function filterSuccessiveDuplicates($array)
{
    $result = array();

    $lastValue = null;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        // Only add non-duplicate successive values
        if ($value !== $lastValue) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }

        $lastValue = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```