# Removing duplicates entries from a multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a the following array structure how can I process it in such a way so as to remove all the successive occurrences of change_status. Please see the array below and then what I want to achieve.

```
$a=array( 
    "0" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "1" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "2" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "3" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "4" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "5" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "6" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "7" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "8" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "9" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "10" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "11" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "12" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" )
    );
```

After processing the above array I would like to have the following

```
$a=array( 
    "0" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "1" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "7" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "8" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "9" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" )
    );
```

Any ideas will be appreciated. I do have a code that deals with the one dimensional array but this one is confusing me and I am a bit slow when dealing with the arrays.

Comment: You asked this question not long ago. [What happened to answer here?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17712070/612717)

Comment: Oh didn't look at that thanks a lot for your help guys

Comment: this is not really a "array remove duplicate"... cause he want to remove duplicate entry with a logic... removing all the duplicates the expected results will be an array of 2 items, and not what he want.

Comment: Hi @Chibueze Opata the other function worked but i want another function that can work on the multidimensional arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with following code

```
$source=array( 
    "0" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "1" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "2" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "3" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "4" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "5" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "6" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "7" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "8" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2" ),
    "9" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "10" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "11" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" ),
    "12" => array(  "status_change" => "start", "clock_status" => "1" )
    );

function reduce_successive(&$source) {      
    $prev_status = 'none';
    foreach($source as $key=>$item) {
        if($item['status_change'] == $prev_status) {
            unset($source[$key]);
        } else {
            $prev_status = $item['status_change'];
        }
    }
}
reduce_successive($source);
var_dump( $source );
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the array while keeping track of the previous element. If the current element is equal to the previous, remove it:

```
$previous = null;
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === $previous) {
        unset($a[$key]);
    }
    $previous = $value;
}
```

Note that I have chosen to use the identity operator `===` to compare the previous and current value because this looks the most fitting for the data you give. If the data format can vary you would need to use a looser form of comparison.

Comment: will this really remove all duplicates? or only those which goes in a row?

Comment: I think you missed the line to assign value to `$previous` in loop

Comment: @insanebits: Those in a row, as the question says "successive duplicates".

Comment: Oh sorry missed this one :)

Comment: Thank you very much Jon :-) worked like a charm :) any ideas about how to do this using recursion?

Comment: Actually $previous will save only the value of the one previous, means, it won't remove those who are multiple time there, since it will look for the previous which will never be the same or in rare cases and won't check for others cases.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra: It's right there...

Comment: @WajidAbbasi: It's not clear what "using recursion" means. Specify things more precisely.

Comment: @Jon : Yeah it is there now, It was not there before :)

Comment: @mike27015 see third comment

Comment: @PrasanthBendra: I forgot it initially, but I put it in seconds after posting the answer. Your comment was quite a bit later, so I thought you 'd have seen it directly. Sorry.

Comment: @Jon : No prob...I just pointed it...Actually it is the problem with my internet it is very slow :D

Comment: Hi Jon using recursion means any recursion function where i can pass an array and then decide to make a decision  based on the value in a row not the entire row for example if the above array is to become "1" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2", "number"=>"1" ),"1" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2", "number"=>"2" ),"1" => array(  "status_change" => "stop", "clock_status" => "2", "number"=>"3" )); then i want to make decision based on the status_change rather than the whole row

Comment: @WajidAbbasi: That's not recursion. Simply replace `===` with an different check.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use the object and array_unique for this kind of task:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $key;
    public $value;
    private $group;
    public function __construct($k,$v,$group=0)
    {
        $this->key=$k;
        $this->value=$v;
            $this->group=$group;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return$this->key."_".$this->value."_".$this->group;
    }
}
$arr=array();
$arr[]=new Test("start",1);
$arr[]=new Test("stop",2);
$arr[]=new Test("stop",2);
$arr[]=new Test("stop",2);

$arr=array_unique($arr);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

And for each "start" key you can increment your group iterator.